# Скопировать из текста дубликаты (или удалить уникальные строки), как?

Tags: текст

Имеется текстовый файл - 900 000 строк.

Как мне из него можно вытащить только дубликаты или же удалить уникальные строки, оставив дубликаты?
Помогите пожалуйста, спасибо.

Можно Windows, можно Linux.

Имеется:

```
asd 
asd 
asd 
asd 
fad 
dfg
```

Скопировать в отдельный файл, нужно дублирующие строки, т.е

```
asd
asd
asd 
asd
```

Либо же удалить из файла уникальные строки, оставив дубликаты.

Comment: Что значит "вытащить дубликаты"? Приведите примерные вход и ожидаемый выход.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение для Linux

[`uniq`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) - report or omit repeated lines.

---

Если надо вернуть дубликаты столько раз, сколько они встречаются:

> `-D     print all duplicate lines`

```bsh
cat input_file | uniq -D
```

---

Если дубликаты нужны только в одном экземпляре:

> `-d, --repeated
>                 only print duplicate lines, one for each group`

```bsh
cat input_file | uniq -d
```

---

Для записи в файл добавьте `> output_file` в конец.